# How to dynamically switch between "WHERE column-name = value" and "WHERE column-name IS NOT NULL"

Tags: c#, sqlite, dynamic, parameters

I am creating a small Visual Studio Windows Form application in C#, and I am using SQLite as my database. Suppose the db stores data for school club members, and they have a value for the state they live in. I am trying to create a parameterized query string so that if the user selects "All States" in my program, then it will load all members. But if they select a specific state, then it will only show members living in that state. How can I dynamically switch between, for example, `WHERE USstate = 'FL'` and `WHERE USstate IS NOT NULL` when using a parameterized query string? I want the value of the state to be dynamically chosen, but if "All States" (a check box) is selected, then all records in the db should show up.

Code example of what is not working for me:

```
string queryString = @"Select * from Membership WHERE USstate = @state;";
List<SQLiteParameter> paramList = new List<SQLiteParameter>();
paramList = addStateParam(paramList);

private List<SQLiteParameter> addStateParam(List<SQLiteParameter> paramList)
    {
        if (!checkBoxFilterAllStates.Checked)
        {
            string selectedState = comboBoxFilterState.Items[comboBoxFilterState.SelectedIndex].ToString();
            var usState = new SQLiteParameter("@state", selectedState);
            paramList.Add(usState);
        }
        else
        {
            var usState = new SQLiteParameter("@state", "IS NOT NULL");
            paramList.Add(usState);
        }
        return paramList;
    }
```

I tried changing `USstate = @state` to just `USstate @state` and then having `@state` replaced with either `"= " + selectedState` or `IS NOT NULL`, but if there is no equal sign before the `@state`, an syntax or logic error appears every time. However, if I do keep the equals sign, then the `IS NOT NUll` code will not work.

How do I dynamically fix this issue? Thanks in advance! And sorry if I was too wordy or redundant.

Comment: I dont know C# but can't you use an `if-else` based on @state value and assign value to `queryString` based on that?

Comment: You'll have to dynamically change the query string.  That or something like `where (@state is null AND USstate Is Not Null) Or USstate = @state` and set the parameter to `DBNull`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select * from Membership WHERE USstate = @state
```

change this to

```
Select * from Membership WHERE USstate like @state
```

after that

```
var usState = new SQLiteParameter("@state", selectedState);
```

to

```
var usState = new SQLiteParameter("@state","%"+selectedState+"%");
```

and finally

```
var usState = new SQLiteParameter("@state", "IS NOT NULL");
```

to

```
var usState = new SQLiteParameter("@state", "%");
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted to do!

Answer (score 0):

If the checkbox is not checked you will have > UsState = IS NOT NULL
You can't check that with a "="-Operator.If you use a sqlitecommand with your selectstring as commandtext you could than do:

> SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(selectstring);
>   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", " = "+state);

Or

> cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", " IS NOT NULL");

Comment: This is what I had tried since I couldn't put the "=" before the IS NOT NULL. But using "USstate @state" in the query string always caused a "syntax or logic error", even if i use (" = " + state).

Comment: With MySQLCommand parameters.Addwithvalue it works. (Parameters.add not)

Answer (score 0):

When you have `WHERE USstate = @state` in the query, then the column value gets compared to the string value passed as parameter. (It is the whole purpose of parameters to avoid being interpreted as SQL commands.)

You have to change the query itself:

```
if (!checkBoxFilterAllStates.Checked)
{
    queryString = @"Select * from Membership WHERE USstate = @state;";
    ...
    paramList.Add(usState);
}
else
{
    queryString = @"Select * from Membership WHERE USstate IS NOT NULL;";
}
```